# How can I group a string only if preceeded by a character, but ignore if the character is missing?

Tags: regex

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm a bit lost myself.

I have the following (sample of) strings I've been retrieving while scraping government datas:

```
- Responsable administrative et financière - 01 02 03 04 05
- Gestionnaire travaux d'entretien sur les monuments historiques (Titre 3 - fonctionnement) et contrôle scientifique et technique sur les MH inscrits - Ille-et-Vilaine - 01 02 03 04 05
- Conseiller
- Ingénieure des services culturels urbanisme et environnement
```

As you can see, some of them have a phone number (the last 10 numbers after the final dash for the 2 firsts lines), and some don't.

I'm looking for a way to group everything from after the first dash to the end, and if there is a dash, to make another group with the phone number in it.

So, with my input, I'd like to get the following back:

```
group1: "Responsable administrative et financière"
group2: "01 02 03 04 05"

group1: "Gestionnaire travaux d'entretien sur les monuments historiques (Titre 3 - fonctionnement) et contrôle scientifique et technique sur les MH inscrits - Ille-et-Vilaine"
group2: "01 02 03 04 05"

group1: "Conseiller"

group1: "Ingénieure des services culturels urbanisme et environnement"
```

The closest I've been with regex is the following:

```
/- (.*)(?: - (.*))/gm
```

But then I don't really know where to go, since if I add a "?" to make the second part optional, then it matches everything, so I'm a bit lost. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/CoLRpz/1)

How should I proceed?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match any char except a `-` in the second part, and make that part optional while the first part is non greedy:

```
^- (.*?)(?: - ([^-\n]*))?$
```

- `^-`  Start of string, and match `-`
- `(.*?)` Captture group 1, match any char except a newline, as least as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-` Match literally
  - `([^-\n]*)` Capture group 2, match optional chars other than `-` and a newline
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V906lg/1)

Comment: I would never have figured it out myself, thanks a lot!